# Boa prática de chamar função PHP

Tags: php

Inicio: em outra página que tem o HTML, chamando uma função PHP pelo Ajax.
No PHP: Chamo uma função PHP através do seguinte código:

```
//pego o nome da função que foi passada para o campo hidden
@$funcao = $_REQUEST["action"];
/* usei REQUEST porque dependendo do que você for fazer você pode querer enviar via get o nome da função dai ela sera pega do mesmo jeito, porque REQUEST recebe dados via GET, POST, e COOKIE */

if (function_exists($funcao)) {
//call_user_func Chama uma função de usuário dada pelo primeiro parâmetro
    call_user_func($funcao);
}
```

Acontece que quando vou chamar a função salvar, todos os objetos e `select` são feitos novamente, e isso só como má prática. E se eu chamar o método salvar antes de criar os objetos, eles ficam `null`.

```
$conexao = new Conexao();
$cliente = new Cliente();

//Recebe ID do cliente da lista - @ para não dar erro
@$cliente_id = $_GET['cliente_id'];   

//pego o nome da função que foi passada para o campo hidden
@$funcao = $_REQUEST["action"];
/* usei REQUEST porque dependendo do que você for fazer você pode querer enviar via get o nome da função dai ela sera pega do mesmo jeito, porque REQUEST recebe dados via GET, POST, e COOKIE */

if (function_exists($funcao)) {
//call_user_func Chama uma função de usuário dada pelo primeiro parâmetro
    call_user_func($funcao);
}

function salvar() {
    //Variáveis globais
    global $conexao, $cliente;

    //Variáveis pegando valores passado pelo post
    $nome = $_POST['nome'];
    $nome_f = $_POST['nome-f'];

    //Preenchendo o objeto.
    $cliente->setNome($nome);
    $cliente->setF($nome_f);

     //Salvando no banco de dados
    $conexao->saveCliente($cliente);

}
```

Como faço para chamar o método salvar sem precisar chamar os objetos novamente e sem eles ficarem nulos?

Comment: recomendo a leitura do padrão [PSR-1](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-1/pt-br/)

Comment: A quantidade de más práticas que você usa aí neste código é enorme, começando pelos comentário sem importância alguma, uso de variáveis globais, criação de variáveis desnecessárias, forçar o `@` como se solucionasse alguma coisa e provavelmente o uso da função `call_user_func`, sem falar que você está buscando mais uma receita de bolo que provavelmente será aplicada errada em outro lugares, mas não entendi o problema e onde quer chegar. O código é tão estranho e a descrição do que deveria fazer é incompleta que não consigo iniciar a ajuda de forma apropriada..

Comment: Nem falei das inconsistências, problemas de segurança, etc.

Comment: Não sabia que meu código usava tanta más práticas. Tudo isso é que quando pelo javascript passo o nome da função salvar,  e o código entra no php, eu as variáveis conexão e cliente ficam nulos porque não foram instanciadas. Estou usando assim porque onde fica a parte html eu faço um include once e passo essa página php, e através dela tem todos os processos, como mostrar cliente de uma lista, salvar e enviar para o servidor.

Comment: e se você passar um parametro a mais na chamada ajax, e no php vc tomar decisoes de acordo com esse parametro?

Comment: O segredo nesse caso: Nunca confie 100% no cliente

Comment: Qual parâmetro eu passaria? Não entendi direito.

Comment: Alguns detalhes: `global` = má prática (instancie seus objetos dentro de cada função); `@` = má prática (faça verificações com `isset` e utilize `try/catch` onde necessário); sua classe `Conexão` possui o método `save` para cada objeto? = má prática.

Comment: Toda vez que eu fazer uma função que usa o objeto cliente eu vou ter que instanciar? E se eu precisar usar o mesmo cliente em outra função, não terei que usar o global?

Comment: Oeslei, segui seus conselhos e usei o $_SESSION, deu certo. Obrigado.

Comment: Como já dito, seu código está fora dos padrões atuais de boas práticas de programação em PHP, inconsistente e inseguro. Sugiro que estude este site de referências com conceitos atuais sobre boas práticas: http://br.phptherightway.com/

Comment: Eu não aconselhei a utilizar a `$_SESSION`, é outra coisa que deves evitar. Utilize a `$_SESSION` apenas para o que é realmente necessário. O que quis dizer foi exatamente o que você imaginou: instancie o objeto em cada função que irá usá-lo. Usando global você pode até mesmo encontrar problemas ao utilizar o objeto que já foi utilizado em outra função, gerando resultados inesperados.